# How Can One Download Cocoalumberjack?

Tags: ios, logging, cocoalumberjack

I'm sold on [Cocoalumberjack](http://code.google.com/p/cocoalumberjack/) as an NSLog replacement. But I'm not finding any easy way to download the source. The Google Code site has all the source, but no downloads. One can clone the Mercurial repository locally, but I don't have Mercurial so the "hg" command line won't work for me. With RCS, CVS, Subversion and Git already installed on my workstation I just don't need or want one more version control system cluttering up my box or my decision making process next time I start a new project.

I'm at the point were I'm about to copy and paste the code from the Browse section of the Google Code site which is hosting the Cocoalumberjack project, and that seems kind of silly/time consuming (although I'm guessing I could have been done with that in the amount of time it has taken me to craft this question.)

Am I missing something? Or is installing Mercurial the only way to download the project?

Thanks.

Comment: You've got 4 VCS clients installed and one more will break you? And you're willing to manually copy/paste the code files instead? Time for perspective check.

Comment: Daniel, that is exactly why I'm asking. As soon as I realized how crazy it would be to copy and paste I stopped and wondered if there was a less crazy way to go about it, short of installing and learning yet another version control system. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to learn how to use Mercurial ... it's one command, and they give you the exact syntax. You literally have to copy and paste `
hg clone https://cocoalumberjack.googlecode.com/hg/ cocoalumberjack` to a command prompt. (Hm, it appears inline code snippets don't work in comments anymore, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless someone from the project uploads an archive of the repository, yes, it appears that using the Mercurial client is the only way to get a copy of the code.

For what it's worth, if all you do is download the CLI, it won't be "cluttering up your box", unless one more folder will really do that to you. As far as I know, the CLI doesn't do anything (like running any services) unless you explicitly tell it to. You could also always uninstall it when you're done.

Comment: Downloading Mercurial took 8.5 MB of my hard drive and about twenty seconds of my time. Syncing up the cocoalumberjack took another ten seconds or so. Thanks for being the voice of reason Daniel!

Comment: Ha, glad I could be of service :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the current distribution is now on github, and has a link to download the repository as a zip file:

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack